# Serialization of an array of mixed(different) objects using JMS Serializer

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I have two different entities called "GuideQueryResult.php" and "NonVerifiedGuideProfile.php".  GuideQueryResult.php is mapped to MongoDB and NonVerifiedGuideProfile is mapped to MySQL.

I also have another class called "SearchResults" that contains a variable "$results".  $results is an array of both "GuideQueryResult.php" and "NonVerifiedGuideProfile.php".

```
class SearchResults {
   /**
   * @Serializer\Type("array<AppBundle\Document\GuideQueryResult>")
   *
   * @var array
   */
   protected $results;
}
```

How would I change the above to make results serialize with both GuideQueryResult as well as NonVerifiedGuideProfile?

The error I am getting when trying to serialize results:

```
Cannot access protected property AppBundle\Entity\NonVerifiedGuideProfile::$_id
```

Comment: what is your error when you try to serialize `$results` ?

Comment: The error I am getting is "Cannot access protected property AppBundle\Entity\NonVerifiedGuideProfile::$_id"